# Ember cli mirage error: patch handler cannot read property update of null

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I am using ember cli mirage with my amber app, i have data defined in fixtures and using the RestSerializer, i am trying to simulate updating the attributes of a record but getting an error: The patch handler for the url api/survey-groups/[id] threw an error: cannot read property update of null

**mirage/config.js**

```
 this.patch('/survey-groups/:id', function({ surveyGroups }, request) {
let id = request.params.id;
let attrs = this.normalizedRequestAttrs();

return surveyGroups.find(id).update(attrs);
```

});

**mirage/serializers/application.js**

```
import { RestSerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default RestSerializer.extend({
primaryKey: 'keyId'});
```

**app/serializers/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
primaryKey: 'keyId', });
```

sample of fixture; mirage/fixtures/survey-groups.js

```
export default [
  {
    "code": "dfdj", 
    "description": "", 
    "keyId": 29116, 
  }, 
  {...... }]
```

I also noticed in the data returned by the server that an id attribute was added to each record, with a string value e.g. id: "1"
When i attempt to find a record using this string value in place of the id, the record is returned.

What could be causing this error and behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ember-cli-mirage`'s Serializer does not have an `primaryKey` option. As far as I'm aware of mirage does not provide any possibility to customize the name of the primary key. Therefore you can't use `find` method. I would recommend to use `findBy` instead: `return surveyGroups.findBy({ keyId: id }).update(attrs);`

Another option would be to use change the name of primary key on serialization ([`serialize`](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/serializers/#serializeresponse-request)) and normalization ([`normalize`](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/serializers/#normalizejson)) of the payload. This approach has the benefit that you are still able to use mirage's [shorthands](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/shorthands/).